# Advanced Select

Tags: mysql, select, join

We have 4 tables:

```
mysql> desc Products;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| product_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc Vendors;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| vendor_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vendor    | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc Prices;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| price_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| vendor_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price      | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc Bought;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| bought_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date       | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pieces     | int(11) | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

now we need some complex select statements, to get the tables we need:

first table need columns [**vendor, product, price, vendors**(that offers the product)].

second table should show what was bought between $date1 and $date2 [**product, pieces, vendor, price, date**]

last table should show what could've been saved in the given time [**vendor**(the cheapest vendor for the product), **product, pcs, price**(for one product), **sum**(price for n products)].

As this wouldnt be complicated enaugh, the resulting tables have to show the names, instead of a key. We were sitting on this the hole day, but none of us have the knowledge to perform needed searches, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you even try to break the problem down? For instance, the need to show names instead of IDs does not complicate the solution at all, as all it means is you need some extra simple JOINs so pull in the names. Also the description for at least the first result set you want is vague. Why does it have both "vendor" and "vendors"? Also shouldn't your Bought table reference the Vendor in some manner? Also, it might not be a good idea to use doubles for prices.

Comment: By first, second and last "tables", do you mean queries?

Comment: @Matti - "might not be a good idea" => "is a horrible idea"

Comment: @Donnie: I'm trying to avoid making yet another person "afraid of floating point". I've ran into people so morbidly afraid of floating point numbers that they questioned the usage of them for map coordinates (as if a off-by-one-billionth error is going to matter when discussing locations at the city level). Using them is all right as long as you understand their limitations and are careful. It's true though, that a fixed point representation is usually better for currency values.

Comment: Yes, i ment queries. Why it's bad to use doubles, should we use float? Yes, i forget to add vendor_id to Bought table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for selecting data from multiple tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Prices LEFT JOIN (Vendors, Products)
                 ON (Products.product_id=Prices.product_id AND Vendors.vendor_id=Prices.vendor_id)
```